# Didn't find class DexPathList

Tags: java, android

```
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
> "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac" on path:
> DexPathList[[zip file
> "/data/app/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/lib/arm,
> /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

Comment: Please add more detail.

Comment: Getting this error in android 6 below mobiles, unable to find the solution please help.i was testing in 5.1.1 android mobile

Comment: Please post your logcat error here.